# Uget is not working

Tags: uget

Uget was working fine until one day suddenly everything disappeared from the uget screen.

This is how it looks now. 
[image]

I uninstalled it twice and reinstalled it only to see this exact screen. I can't understand if it is downloading or not in the background.

My pc runs on Ubuntu 16.04

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems config files of your uGet got corrupted somehow.

If you can afford to do that (you'll lose all uGet configurations), remove the broken config files, i.e. remove the `~/.config/uGet/` directory while uGet is closed and then launch the application.

Comment: it's really helped me, thank you